# Selenium IDE and php code coverage

Tags: php, code-coverage, selenium-ide

I have a few test suites written in selenium IDE (data driven) , and I do not find export test suite  option for php (phpunit) probably missing plugin.

So my question is how I can setup some tools to still generate code coverage while running selenium IDE tests. I still need those beautiful code coverage reports generated by phpunit+xdebug :)

## Edit

I have installed [php_codecoverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage) , through pears . After updating prepend/append.php files 
I get this half done report without source files/line details.

[image]

Now I need to fix this issue and also add some directories to blacklist (e.g 
 xamppfiles/*)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but you can get the [PHP formatters for Selenium IDE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-php-formatters/) at the Mozilla addons website. You will have to tweak the data driven parts after the export.

Comment: I have managed to create code coverage with Selenium IDE Tests, bit slow by working great

Comment: To setup I have to update auto_prepend.php/auto_append.php to start(before first test run)/ stop(at the end of all tests) on desired place and on after each test run , merge the coverage data with previous one and generate the report after final test run ( e.g when stoping coverage) . I use a cookie to handle this e.g url.php?_cc=start and url.php?_cc=stop. :)